# system() output to a char* 

Tags: c, file, system

```
int system(const char *)
```

How can I send output of this command (lets say the command is "pwd") to a char*? Its returning an int but I want the results of the command to be sent to a char*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pipe the output of the command directly to a file by using "pwd > tempfile" as command.
Another way is to use `popen`

```
FILE *output = popen("pwd", "r");
```

That will give you a file pointer where you can read the output from.

Answer (score 5):

system("pwd > file");

system() uses "/bin/sh -c" under Linux so it can do anything a shell command line can do.

Comment: Thanks Richard. How can I put it into a string instead of a file? Possible?

Comment: Nice comment, but did you notice that the question was edited from the original that asked specifically about files?